# Filter an array of objects based on array property containing all values from another array

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I have an array of objects:

`const breeds=[{name: 'Golden', temperament: ['friendly', 'kind', 'smart']},{name: 'Husky', temperament: ['alert', 'loyal', 'gentle']},{name: 'Yorkshire Terrier', temperament: ['bold', 'independent', 'kind']}]`

I would like to sort them by selected "temperament." Let's say a user has selected both "kind" & "friendly", it should only return "Golden".

I'm using javascript and underscore and this is what I have tried so far:

```
 //selected is an array of selected temperaments
 //breeds is the array of objects
function filterTemperaments(selected, breeds) {
  return _.filter(breeds, function (breed) {
    if (!breed.temperament) breed.temperament = "";
    const breedList = breed.temperament;
    return breedList.includes(...selected);
  }, selected);
}
```

This seems to only be returning breeds that match the first temperament in the selected array. For example if selected is `['kind', 'loyal']` and the breed is `{name:'Golden', temperament: ['kind', 'smelly']}`, Golden will still come back as true, despite not matching the "Loyal" temperament

Any thoughts for a better solution here? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return only those breeds which have [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) temperament selected

```js
const breeds=[{name: 'Golden', temperament: ['friendly', 'kind', 'smart']},{name: 'Husky', temperament: ['alert', 'loyal', 'gentle']},{name: 'Yorkshire Terrier', temperament: ['bold', 'independent', 'kind']}],
    selected = ['kind', 'friendly']

const filtered = breeds.filter(b => selected.every(s => b.temperament.includes(s)))

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: instead of `every` it should be a `some` because if the selected is ['loyal', 'smart'] you dont get results, and you should get 2 results because 2 dogs matches those selections.

Comment: @PrinceHernandez but OP wants to match every temperament selected: *"Let's say a user has selected both "kind" & "friendly", it should only return "Golden"."*

Comment: @adiga Is correct, I am looking for "every". Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: you are totally right, I missunderstood it with the second statement of the question.

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to use using `filter` and `every` in order to know if you got any matches and return the matched values.

```js
const breeds = [{
  name: 'Golden',
  temperament: ['friendly', 'kind', 'smart']
}, {
  name: 'Husky',
  temperament: ['alert', 'loyal', 'gentle']
}, {
  name: 'Yorkshire Terrier',
  temperament: ['bold', 'independent', 'kind']
}]

//selected is an array of selected temperaments
//breeds is the array of objects
function filterTemperaments(selected, breeds) {
  return breeds.filter(({ temperament }) => { //here I'm desctructuring the object only to get the temperaments.
    return selected.every(selection => temperament.indexOf(selection) !== -1)
  })

}

const result = filterTemperaments(['kind', 'friendly'], breeds);
console.log(result)
```